# Two standard dice are rolled together. What is the probability of rolling a sum less than 7 or a sum divisible by 5?

Tags: probability

This is what I got so far

Sum less than 7:  $(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(4,1),(4,2),(5,1)$.

15 ways

15/36

Sum divisible by 5: $( 1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1)$

4 ways

4/36

I don't what to do with "or"

Does Or means to add $15/36+ 4/36$?

I need help with getting the final situations

Comment: You missed the sums of $10.$ the sums of $5$ don’t add any additional cases.

Comment: What do you mean sum of 10?

Comment: $(6,4),(5,5),(4,6)$

Comment: Ok now i understand but what am u i suppose to do to get the final answer since it says "or"

Comment: "or" in mathematics is almost always non-exclusive.  That is, if $A,B$ are two properties something might have, saying that "$A$ or $B$" holds does not exclude the cases in which both $A,B$ hold.  If a writer wants to indicate an exclusive or they should specify that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Inclusion-exclusion.  $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$

---

The sums who are less than $7$ you listed already.  There are $1+2+3+4+5 = 15$ of these

The sums who are multiples of $5$ (*who might or might not be less than seven*) you wrote only a few of, having incorrectly only written those who are *both* multiples of five *and* less than seven.  You missed also the three cases of $(6,4),(5,5),(4,6)$ for a total of $4+3=7$ ways.

Now, we wanted to see how many ways of rolling the dice (*in sequence*) satisfied at least one of these conditions.  To do that, we add the respective counts... *however* in doing so we added those outcomes who satisfied *both* too many times so we correct the count by subtracting the amount who satisfied both so that the overall effect is that they were added only once.

$15 + 7 - 4 = 18$ ways and a probability of $\frac{18}{36}=\frac{1}{2}$

---

Recall:

When $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive events (*meaning there is no way for both to happen at the same time*) then we have $\Pr(A\text{ or }B)=\Pr(A\cup B)=\Pr(A)+\Pr(B)$.  This is not true for general $A,B$ however if they are able to overlap.  The correct statement is $\Pr(A\cup B) = \Pr(A)+\Pr(B)-\Pr(A\cap B)$

When $A$ and $B$ are *independent* events (*loosely meaning that they don't impact one another's chances of occurring*) then you have $\Pr(A\text{ and }B)=\Pr(A\cap B) = \Pr(A)\times \Pr(B)$.  This is not true for general $A,B$ however if they might influence one another.  The correct general statement is $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\times \Pr(B\mid A)$ using conditional probability.

Comment: I don't know how to use this formula. can you please explain further? thank you

Comment: @Foul_k expanded

Comment: Thank you so muchhhhh I understand now

Answer (score 0):

@ThomasAndrews notes that you forgot to count $(5,5)$, $(4,6)$ and $(6,4)$ as outcomes divisible by $5$. In fact, all the remaining divisible by $5$ outcomes are already included in the "less than $7$" category. In order to compute the probability  for the "or" you need to sum the probabilities of the separate cases **and** subtract the probability of the joint case, i.e., sum less than $7$ and is divisible by $5$. Otherwise you'd be counting some events twice. The list of outcomes that are less than $7$ or divisible by $5$ is $(1,1)$, $(1,2)$, $(1,3)$, $(1,4)$, $(1,5)$, $(2,1)$, $(2,2)$, $(2,3)$, $(2,4)$, $(3,1)$, $(3,2)$, $(3,3)$, $(4,1)$, $(4,2)$, $(5,1)$, $(5,5)$, $(4,6)$ and $(6,4)$ That's $18$ ways so the probability needs to be $\frac{18}{36}$. If you add the separate probabilities you'd have $\frac{15}{36}+\frac{7}{36}=\frac{22}{36}$, which is clearly wrong. Of the $7$ cases that are divisible by $5$, $4$ are also such that they add up to less than $7$. The actual probability is, therefore $\frac{15}{36}+\frac{7}{36}-\frac{4}{36}=\frac{18}{36}$, as counting revealed.

Comment: Check your counting... where did you get $19$?

Comment: Don't know where my head is. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You counted all cases manually. Alternatively, you could have used stars and bars.

Number of cases where two dice will show a sum of less than $7$ is equivalent to number of solutions to,

$x_1 + x_2 \lt 5 \ $ or $ \ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 4$

That gives you $ \displaystyle {6 \choose 2} = 15$ solutions.

You can apply this for next part as well but it may be easier to count manually. For example, for the sum to be $10$, there are only $3$ possibilities $(6, 4), (4, 6), (5, 5)$ whereas if you apply stars and bars, you will have to include the restriction that neither of them can be greater than $6$.

Now to calculate probability, as others have suggested, cases where sum is less than $7$ already include cases where sum is multiple of $5$. So in total there are only $15 + 3 = 18$ favorable cases.